# How to delete all files except some files in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

This is my current code, I thought I had figured it out but this just deletes all the files in my directory.

```
$this->load->helper('file');
$videos = get_filenames('z/course/');
    foreach ($videos as $key => $value) {
        if ($value != 'default_video.mp4') {
            delete_files('z/course/'.$value);
        }
    }
```

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Before `delete_files` method, Check `$value` is not empty. Better to use `unlink()` instead of `delete_files`.

Comment: @TamilvananN
Wow  that worked perfectly! thanks

edit : misclick
is there any special reason why i should check if '$value' is empty?

Comment: There is no special reason. `$value` can't be empty, But in case if it's empty then `delete_files` method will delete all files inside the `'z/course/'` directory.

Answer (score 1):

`delete_files()` method for deleting all files inside the given directory.
Ref: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/file_helper.html#delete_files

For deleting an individual file(s), `unlink()` is the method.

```
$this->load->helper('file');
$videos = get_filenames('z/course/');
    foreach ($videos as $key => $value) {
        if ($value != '' && $value != 'default_video.mp4') {
           // delete_files('z/course/'.$value);
           $file = 'z/course/'.$value;
           if (is_readable($file) && unlink($file)) {
              echo "The file has been deleted";
           } else {
              echo "The file was not found or not readable and could not be deleted";
           }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`strpos()`](https://tecadmin.net/check-string-contains-substring-in-php/) function check `default_video.mp4` exists in filename.

```
$this->load->helper('file');
$videos = get_filenames('z/course/');
    foreach ($videos as $key => $value) {
        if (strpos($value, 'default_video.mp4') !== false) {
            delete_files('z/course/'.$value);
        }
    }
```

You should like:

```
if (strpos($value, 'default_video.mp4') !== false) {
   //do something 
 }
```